# Marry a non-muslim women from another traditions

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

Salam Alaikoum,

I know that a muslim man is allowed to marry a christian or jewish women, but should the man go to church for example as the christian tradition ask ?

Comment: Go to the church for what purpose?

Comment: Christian tradition does not ask you to go to church. More important is how you treat the people around you, than going to church. That's how you might be measured. Not by how many times you prayed or went to church.

Answer (score 2):

Wa Alaikum As Salam!

No. Per Islam, the Islamic marriage ceremony is sufficient so he has no need to go to a church nor should he because no evidence allows otherwise.  Umar (RA) said, "We cannot enter these churches of yours with the images which are inside them" - [Al Adab Al Mufrad (1248)](https://sunnah.com/urn/2312450). That applies in general or for marriage ceremonies.

You can read ['here'](https://islamqa.info/en/242423) for a scholarly opinion on a Muslim's marriage in a church by a priest. (*Also note, as another user mentioned... Christian tradition itself doesn't require marriage be in a church*).

Remember, the man is Muslim and is bringing the Christian wife into his ***Muslim household**. Meaning, the marriage will be per Islamic tradition, the house will be kept per Islamic tradition (eg, no Christian symbols like crosses hanging around) and the children will be raised upon Islam.

The Christian wife is limited on the above mentioned but has the freedom to believe whatever she wants and pray/do her rituals as she wants in private. The allowance of marrying women from the 'People of the Book' is not with any risk to the faith of the Muslims involved.